# Keep my files secure from my clients

Tags: php, security, project

I'm freelance PHP Developer, so after finishing the project, I upload this project on Client's site or server, so I need ways to keep my files secure from my client and he can't sold them and modify anything without my permission. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: use Java, or use your own hosting.

Comment: Use a contract and define your clauses :) you will not be able to protect your code against that unless the person you sold it to has no tech knowledge whatsoever and let's no one else access it.

Comment: Unless you have a specific license the client can do whatever they want. Maybe don't give them the FTP password?

Comment: @ShayElkayam that changes nothing.

Comment: @ShayElkayam, From where did you bring `JAVA` in here ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus LOL simple way = simple solution , yes I can do that :D

Comment: Haha, I always do stuff using the K.I.S.S. method =)

Comment: What is K.I.S.S method . I think it stands for Keep It Simple Stuff ;)

Comment: Yes that is **exactly** what it means :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to save those files in their server , there is no guarantee that you can protect it. You could just deploy a license file and put a *terms of use* on your code. [Something like a *mutual agreement* between the client and yourself, the license file will be a soft copy of your manually signed document]

There are some code *obfuscators* like **ZEND Guard** , **IONEncoder** , but the client should have the neccessary **ZEND Optimizer** to be installed, only then it can render *obfuscated* code.

**The better way is to have your own private server** , do the coding stuff and then deploy it and show it off to your client by giving your server URL.

Comment: You Said "If you are going to save those files in their server , there is no guarantee that you can protect it. You could just deploy a license file that put a terms of use on your code.". So if he delete this license file ?

Comment: Yes you can't depend on that or you both can manually digital sign a document and share it through FAX or something.

Comment: How to give the website to my client on my own server ?!

Comment: Just deploy the files on your server and give the link to your client as.. `http://mohamemgamal.com/test.php`

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend guard or similar softwares. it encrypt php file and nobody can see it's content.
http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

You can search google for php obfuscation to see some solutions

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment above I would recommend to not give them the FTP password.

Comment: He is hosting files on clients server. The clients will ofcourse own the FTP credentials.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha The client only want the site or program runs. FTP credentials for me if he need them . I will use ioncube :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to protect your code stored on the hands of a client who might redistribute the code against your wishes. You have only few options to protect your code, but none of them are perfect.

1. Use a license wich disallows redistribution.
2. Obfuscate your code.

   1. [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)
   2. [sourceguardian](http://www.sourceguardian.com/)
   3. [phpshield](http://www.phpshield.com/)
   4. [phpcipher](http://www.phpcipher.com/)
   5. [truebug](http://www.truebug.com/)
   6. [bcompiler](http://pecl.php.net/package/bcompiler)
   7. [phc](http://phpcompiler.org/index.html)
   8. [Thicket™ Obfuscator for PHP](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/obfuscators/PHPObfuscator.html)
   9. [Monas free php encoder/decoder](http://ombudi.com/)
   10. [PHTML Encoder](http://www.rssoftlab.com/phpenc.php)
3. Encrypt your code.

Obfuscations and encryptions can always be broken and license is just a threat for taking action if the clauses are not followed. Client could possibly sell the code without you knowing, because the world is big place. The only real solution if you are paranoid about this kind of thing is to host the code yourself and ask them to pay for the hosting and maintance of the code.

You could always develop kind of license code system which asks your server to check if the client has right to use the software, but these checks are quite easy to remove from software if it does not need reverse engineering. Though you could also make the software to retrieve decryption key from your server over Internet before decrypting the code for running.

Everything can be broken with time and power, but you have to make it so hard that it requires more than the client has if you are so paranoid the client will do something you do not like.

For example I have never had the need to protect my PHP code from clients, because I do not really care if they resell the software or not. I just make sure I get paid for my time developing the software.